# Twig template file not found in service

Tags: symfony, templates, service, twig

Rendering a twig template inside a controller works like charm.
But i have to render the template inside a service, and this won't work:

> "Unable to find template file ..."

The service is container-aware and has "container" already injected.

I've tried different ways to set the template file:

```
$this->container->get('templating')
     ->render('AppBundle:Email:mytemplate.html.twig');
$this->container->get('templating')
     ->render('src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Email/mytemplate.html.twig');
```

always the same error...
The template file exists in
*/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Email/mytemplate.html.twig*
(double-checked!)

This controller call works:

```
$this->get('templating')
     ->render('AppBundle:Email:mytemplate.html.twig');
```

**Why this won't work in my service...?**

Comment: `$this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle:Email:mytemplate.html.twig');` should work.... What is exactly the error message ?

Comment: "Unable to find template file 'AppBundle:Email:mytemplate.html.twig'"

Comment: Try `@AppBundle/Email/mytemplate.html.twig`

Comment: Please show your directory tree from src to the template.

Comment: `/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Email/mytemplate.html.twig`